# dynamically submit form when values change python

Tags: python, html, django, dynamic

I am new to html and Django and trying to make my forms dynamically auto-submit whenever the user changes their inputs, essentially removing the 'Submit' button.

My form has 3 inputs, (all floats) which will go through a 'some_function()' for a calculation. But to save the user time, I would like it dynamic. Hence, no 'submit'.

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
          <h3>Calculator</h3>
          <form method="post" >
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form_c.as_p }}
              <button type="submit">Submit</button> # <- I would like to remove this
          </form>
    </div>
```

My View is below if needed:

```
 def post(self, request):
        form_c = CalculatorForm(request.POST, prefix='form_c')
        try:
            if form_c.is_valid():
                post = form_c.cleaned_data
                val1 = float(post.get('val1'))
                val2 = float(post.get('val2'))
                val3 = float(post.get('val3'))
                numbers = some_function(val1, val2, val3)

        except:
            pass

        args = {
            'form_c': form_c, 'form_cols': numbers,
        }
        return render(request, self.template, args)
```

(EDIT) Forms:

```
class CalculatorForm(forms.Form):
    val1 = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, min_value=0.0, required=False)
    val2 = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, min_value=0.0, required=False)
    val3 = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, min_value=0.0, required=False)
```

Comment: This is a javascript question. You need your JS to validate then send the request once all fields are filled in and valid. However, `some_function` may be called an arbitrary amount of times if you're sending that request under the conditions of new data, and valid data. Also, new and valid data isn't always the intended data.

Comment: @Codesidian so this isn't possible with what I have currently? Do you know how it would be done in JS? I have never used it before. Cheers

Comment: No, it isn't possible with what you **currently have**, but implementing the functionality you want would be quite trivial. However, I was highlighting more design questions rather than anything specific to your current implementation. Asking whether or not you should rather than if you could. If some_function can run an arbitrary amount of times, then yes sure. Can it be run safely with unintentional data? Should it be run a hell of a lot of times per user? There's a reason why the functionality you're requesting isn't popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will achieve what you're requesting in the simplest way possible. Although I haven't tested it, the logic is there. You can create the validation and submit function in JS then call it when an input field is changed using the `onChange` attribute. [You just need to add the attribute to your inputs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs). You can also just [add event listeners to your inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) or [use jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to do away with the onchange attribute. It's up to you.

**view.py**

```
def post(self, request):
        form_c = CalculatorForm(request.POST, prefix='form_c')
        try:
            if form_c.is_valid():
                post = form_c.cleaned_data
                val1 = float(post.get('val1'))
                val2 = float(post.get('val2'))
                val3 = float(post.get('val3'))
                numbers = some_function(val1, val2, val3)

        except:
            pass

        args = {
            'form_c': form_c, 'form_cols': numbers,
        }
        return render(request, self.template, args)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
      <h3>Calculator</h3>
      <form method="post" id="myform" name="myform">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form_c.as_p }}
      </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validate_then_submit() {
    var valid = false;
    //validate form here
    if (valid == true) {
        document.forms['myform'].submit();
    }
}
```

**forms.py**

```
class fooForm(forms.Form):
    char_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onChange':'validate_then_submit()'}))
```

However, I don't think any of this is good design. If the form submits as soon as the data is "valid", what if there was a typo? It takes the control away from the user and acts in a way that's unexpected.

Comment: Thanks! I still haven't got it quite working yet but will let you know. I should've been more clear on the Forms (I have added my form in my question). I agree with your statement but I'm hoping with these constraints in the DecimalField that it won't be a problem.

I wanted it to behave like excel, so when the values change, the output will also.